# How do I install the Android SDK into Netbeans 8.0

Tags: android, netbeans

I have netbeans 8.0 installed and I have the android SDK file downloaded. How do I exactly install the android SDK? I don't see a .exe file or anything like that? Can someone please help me, this is really frustrating.

Answer (score 7):

Netbeans is also a good environment for android developement, you can refer this link for setting android sdk into netbeans :

[https://forums.netbeans.org/topic51543.html](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic51543.html)

Comment: the link seems to be broken at the time of this comment

Answer (score 1):

On a 14.10 Utopic Ubuntu amd64 desktop I had to place the following export in ~/.profile

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/username/adt/sdk
```

Netbeans 8 didn't see the environment variable in the ~/.bashrc, but after exporting it in ~/.profile, Netbeans found the SDK.
Be sure to replace the username and use your local adt install path.